# SQL - Sum of Multiple Duplicate Rows that is Equal to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to query the data's that when the Amount column is added the result would be 0, and has the same ColumnA and ColumnB. But the problem is when I add the ColumnB in the Group By I get the wrong result. It also returns the data that the sum of it is not 0.

Basically:

```
Input:
    ColumnA,       ColumnB,           Amount
    123,             555,               10
    234,             555,              -25
    234,             555,               10
    234,             555,               15
    123,             555,               20
```

Basically the result I want is:

```
ColumnA,       ColumnB,           Amount
        234,             555,              -25
        234,             555,               10
        234,             555,               15
```

Here is the code I found:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ColumnA In
(
SELECT ColumnA FROM table
GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB
HAVING SUM(Amount)
)
```

Any Help on THis Please?

Comment: this is called the subset sum problem - you might need a procedure to solve this

Comment: @Jomari Do you just care about the whole set or about subsets which sum to 0. For example, if in your original data set there was a record {234,555,5} , how would this affect your expected output?

Comment: Sorry for replying late, if you add {234, 555, 5} to the data then nothing would happen since I need the data that has an equivalent value of 0 when added togeher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM t_column t1 -- your table name
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM t_column t2 -- your table name
                WHERE t1.columnA = t2.columnA
                  AND t1.columnB = t2.columnB
               HAVING SUM(amount) = 0
              )
```

Result

```
columnA columnB amount
234     555     -25
234     555     10
234     555     15
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
select columnA
, columnB
, amount 
from table join 
(select columnA A
, columnB B
, sum(amount ) theSum
group by columnA, columnB ) temp on columnA = A 
and columnB = B
where theSum <> 0
```